# If subset Not TOSET then set also Not toset?

Tags: relations, self-learning, order-theory

Toset - totally ordered set

For example, Take $(\mathbb{Z}, |)$ is not toset

Reason $(\{1,3,4,12\}, |)$ subset of above has hasse diagram not a chain

```
    12
  /    \
 3      4      
   \   /
     1
```

So with this can i conclude that $(\mathbb{Z}, |)$ is not toset? if subset not toset can i say set not toset?
Are subsets of all tosets tosets? Converse?
kindly elaborate.

Comment: Correct. $3$ and $4$ are not related in the poset above, and they're not related in $\mathbb Z$ either. In general, if $(P,\leq)$ is a toset (aka, chain, linear ordered set), and $Q \subseteq P$ then $(Q,\leq')$ is also a toset, where $\leq' = \leq \cap Q^2$. So by contra-position, your conjecture is correct.

Comment: you're right! Subsets of totally ordered sets are totally ordered wet the induced ordering

Answer (score 2):

The set-theoretic definition of a binary relation on a set $S$ is some (any) $R\subseteq S\times S.$ But we usually write $xRy$ instead of $(x,y)\in R.$

Let $R$ be a binary relation on $S$. Let $S'\subseteq S$ and let $R'=R\cap (S'\times S').$

(1). Suppose $p,q\in S'$ with $p\ne q$  such that $(p,q)\not\in R'$ and $(q,p)\not\in R'.$ That is, $p,q$ are $R'$-incomparable. Then neither $(p,q)$ nor $(q,p)$ belongs to $S$ because $S'\subseteq S,$ so $p,q$ are also $R$-incomparable.

If  $p,q$ are unequal members of $S'$ and if exactly one member of $\{(p,q),(q,p)\}$ belongs to $R,$ then we also have $\{(p,q),(q,p)\}\subseteq S'\times S',$ so exactly one member of $\{(p,q),(q,p)\}$ belongs to $R\cap (S'\times S')=R'.$

If $p,q$ are unequal members of $S'$ and if exactly one member of $T=\{(p,q),(q,p)\}$ belongs to $R'$ then that member belongs to $R$ because $R'\subseteq R$. But the other member of $T$ cannot belong to $R,$ otherwise $T\subseteq R\cap (S'\times S')=R',$ which would imply both members of $T$ belong to $R'$.

(2). Similarly if $\forall x\in S\;(\,(x,x)\in R)$ (i.e. $R$ is reflexive) then $\forall x\in S'\;(\,(x,x)\in R')....$ OR if $x\in S$ but $(x,x)\not\in R$ then let $S'=\{x\},$ giving an $S'\subseteq S$ and an $x\in S'$ such that $(x,x)\not\in R'.$

In summary a binary relation $R$ on $S$ is total iff $R\cap (S'\times S')$ is total on every $S'\subseteq S$.

Tosets are also called linear orders.

Comment: If we adhered to the the set-theoretic notation we should write $(1,2)\in <$ instead of $1<2.$